# How to UNION with keeping identifying fields?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables that have the same structure but different data.

The structure is like `id, name` for both.

I want to run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "schema1"."items" UNION SELECT * FROM "schema2"."items";
```

This one returns all the rows from both tables which seems almost fine, but I don't know which row belongs to which schema.

How do I add info to them that would help me identify it on query?

Comment: try `tableoid`?..

Comment: Are you still wanting the duplicate elimination that `union` performs? If so, what should happen when there are duplicates in both tables? What should the "distinguishing" data look like in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example strucutre:

```
t=# create schema s1;
CREATE SCHEMA
t=# create schema s2;
CREATE SCHEMA
t=# create table s1.t(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create table s2.t(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into s1.t select 1;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into s2.t select 1;
INSERT 0 1
```

select:

```
t=# select tableoid::regclass,* from s1.t union all select tableoid,* from s2.t;
 tableoid | i
----------+---
 s1.t     | 1
 s2.t     | 1
(2 rows)
```

[tableoid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html) and [regclass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) will make it neat

Answer (score 2):

Add a computed column to the select clause:

```
SELECT *, 1 AS schema_num FROM "schema1"."items"
UNION
SELECT *, 2 FROM "schema2"."items";
```

You may also use this computed column to order the result set, e.g. if you want the `schema1` records to appear before the `schema2` records.

Per Gordon's answer and comments, you might want to use `UNION ALL` here, unless you really intend to filter out duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.*, 'table1' AS TABLE_NAME 
FROM "schema1"."items" a
UNION 
SELECT b.*, 'table2' AS TABLE_NAME 
FROM "schema2"."items" b;
```

So basically you define the values in the column TABLE_NAME and union the 2 queries.

Answer (score 1):

The method is to explicitly include the table name/identifier from each table.  More importantly, though:  use `union all` rather than `union`:

```
SELECT i.*, 'schema1' as schema
FROM "schema1"."items" i
UNION ALL
SELECT i2.*, 'schema2'
FROM "schema2"."items" i2;
```

Why?  `UNION` incurs the overhead of removing duplicates.  The additional column identifying the schema makes it impossible to have duplicates between the two subqueries.  Hence, the additional effort is wasted.  (If you want to remove duplicates from each subquery, use `SELECT DISTINCT`.)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . In this case, I posted on purpose because I wanted to expound on `union all` versus `union`.

Comment: You're right about union all +1 though in this particular case I think we get away with just union because of the computed column for the schema.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . It is the overhead involved and that is precisely why I expound on the point.  In every database I have seen, the execution plan will try to eliminate duplicates -- even if there are none.